# Passo Giau parking fee

Tags: italy, automobiles, fees-and-charges, dolomites

I'm trying to estimate costs of my car trip, and  I'm wondering how much does it cost to leave your car at Passo Giau in Dolomites. If you don't know exact fee, just give me an estimate.

Comment: Er, isn't the Passo Giau a mountain pass?  Where on the pass are you leaving it?  Excuse my ignorance, I've not been to Italy.

Comment: Yes, it's a mountain pass, but it has a parking lot and a road leading to it.

Comment: Zero. Parking's free year 'round!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say for sure, because I have not been in this particular place, but...

There is a restaurant at Passo Giau, so chances are, that the parking place may be free. If not, I think the fee should be around 3 € - that was the price at Passo Sella.